# How to derive age from date column in database using sql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display all users that are in specific age range(eg. between 10 and 20) using `mysqli`. What query will be best to derive the age and how?

I currently have a problem on a query that does not display the accurate result. What I want is to display users between the age this and that but the query below does not give any error but instead display even the age below 10 or above 20. I have 2 tables user and user_likes.

```
        user
        username(pk)   gender   date_of_birth      country
          John           M        2010-12-31        India
          Bing           M        2000-12-31        Italy
          Rose           F        2000-12-01         UK

         user_likes 
         username(fk)    gender     age_from      to_age
         John             F             18            30
         Bing             F             20            30
         Rose             M             18            25
```

The `$username` below is a session stored in that variable.

```
        $sql = "SELECT gender, age_from, to_age FROM user_likes WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $gender1 = $row['gender'];
                $age_from = $row['age_from'];
                $to_age = $row['to_age'];
            }
        }

        $sql1 = "SELECT username, date_of_birth, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS age FROM user WHERE NOT username = '$username' AND gender = '$gender1'  AND (date_of_birth BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql1);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        { 

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {                   
                echo "<div>";
                    echo "<span><a href = 'accounts.php?usernames=".$username."'><img src = '".$row['photo']."' alt = 'profile photo'></span>";
                    echo "<div>".$row['username']."</a><br><span>From".$row['country']."</span></div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }               
        }
```

The problem in the above code is that if i select the age from 18 to 80 even the age below 18 or above 80 is still displayed so I believe it has something to do with

```
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS age
```

or

```
      date_of_birth BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age'
```

What I expect is that -- Suppose I am Rose and since my interest gender is male and selected age range is from 18 to 25 I want only `'Bing'` user to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_of_birth BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age'
```

Let's replace the fields by some values.

```
'2010-12-31' BETWEEN '18' AND '20'
```

This is a non-sense, you may want to rather use

```
...
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age'
```

In example :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  `username` VARCHAR(4),
  `gender` VARCHAR(1),
  `date_of_birth` VARCHAR(10),
  `country` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`username`, `gender`, `date_of_birth`, `country`)
VALUES
  ('John', 'M', '2010-12-31', 'India'),
  ('Bing', 'M', '2000-12-31', 'Italy'),
  ('Rose', 'F', '2000-12-01', 'UK');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT username,
       date_of_birth,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS "age"
FROM users
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '18' AND '20');
```

**Output**

```
| username | date_of_birth | age |
| -------- | ------------- | --- |
| Bing     | 2000-12-31    | 18  |
| Rose     | 2000-12-01    | 18  |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT username,
       date_of_birth,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS "age"
FROM users
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '01' AND '10');
```

**Output**

```
| username | date_of_birth | age |
| -------- | ------------- | --- |
| John     | 2010-12-31    | 8   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jWhn9QQBBisfyNtnwh6xfM/0)

Comment: replacing date_of_birth with age makes it more worse as it does not display anything at all, while date_of_birth displayed all the users instead of only the wanted age range

Comment: True, I did make a little mistake

Comment: Thanks it works, but would you recommend doing it my way or would you prefer other methods?

Comment: You don't have that much choice. This way would be the one I'll use. But I strongly suggest you to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injections

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, your query has a flaw. In

```
...WHERE ... AND (date_of_birth BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age')
```

...you are comparing `date_of_birth` (date) with `age` (integer). It makes no sense, you can get any unexpected result.

Try modifying the WHERE clause so that:

```
...WHERE ... AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age')
```

Final sentence:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT username, date_of_birth, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS age FROM user WHERE NOT username = '$username' AND gender = '$gender1'  AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) BETWEEN '$age_from' AND '$to_age')";
```

Comment: Thanks.... but I have to ask -- why does my query has flaws? and would you prefer other methods?

Comment: Edited with the answer to your comment.